# Are one-point sets always compact in any topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

From the definition of compactness, I think one-point sets are always compact in any topological space. But, I am not sure about my judgement. Am I correct?

Answer (score 9):

Since I was asked to repost my comment as an answer:

Any open cover of *any* topological space is a subset of the power set of the underlying set, and power sets of finite sets are finite. So all open covers of finite spaces are *already* finite; in other words, finite spaces only *have* finitely many open sets.

Comment: "So all open covers of finite spaces are already finite" That doesn't follow. An open cover is a set of elements from the power set of the *topological* space, not of the *covered* space. Consider the set {0}. This has an infinite cover of {(n-2,n+2)} in **R**. So your argument fails to establish that {0} is compact in every topological space.

Comment: @Acccumulation If one considers a finite set $X$ lying inside an ambient space as a topological space with the subspace topology then the OP is correct, since $X$ will only have finitely many open sets to begin with

Comment: Two caveats: Some (French) people include *Hausdorff* in their definition of compact. This certainly holds for singletons, but not for arbitrary finite sets. Second, I would rather say that a cover is a *family* of open sets and what you describe is merely the image of this map, but that does not effect your argument.

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes, as leibnewtz said, I was considering the subspace topology. Inside $\mathbb{R}$, the subset $\{0\}$ has lots of open neighbourhoods. However, the definition of "compactness" doesn't require us to cover $\{0\}$ with *open sets of $\mathbb{R}$*, but with *open sets of $\{0\}$*. There are far fewer of those.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @leibnewtz By "OP", do you mean Keith or Billy? Keith did not ask whether a singleton has a topological space in which it is compact, but rather whether it is compact in *every* topological space. If someone were to ask "Given a continuous function, is the pre-image of an open set an open set?", responding "Sure! *All* sets are open in their own subspace topology" would not be an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Acccumulation "Compactness" isn't relative to an ambient space, whereas "openness of a set" is. I define a subset U of a space X to be compact if U is itself a compact top. space in the subspace topology inherited from X. Maybe you define it differently, e.g. "any collection of open sets of X which covers U can be refined to a *finite* one". But these definitions are equivalent, and my answer remains essentially the same: take a cover of open sets of X, intersect them all with U, find a finite subcover *there, as open sets of U*, and then lift the finite subcover back up to X.

Comment: (As a linguistic point: this is why I called them "finite spaces", i.e. topological spaces on a finite set, rather than "finite subsets of topological spaces". :))

Comment: @Acccumulation We first define compactness intrinsically, and then we say a subset $A \subseteq X$ is compact in some space $X$ *if it's compact in the subspace topology*

Answer (score 6):

Every finite set is compact. This is because, one can *always* find a finite subcover, which can be proven inductively:

Let $X:=\{x_1, \dots x_n\}$ be a  finite set. Suppose that $\{U_x\}$ covers $X$. Take any $U_{x_1}$ that covers $x_1$. Consider $\{U_x\}\setminus U_{x_1}$. Then pick one that  covers $x_2$ if $U_{x_1}$ does not, etc.

Comment: This sounds very indirect to me. Surely the real point is that *any* open cover of *any* topological space is a subset of the power set of the underlying set, and power sets of finite sets are finite!

Comment: You must consider cases because, what happens if $x_2\in U_{x_1}$ and there is not another open set in $\{U_x\}$ such that contains to $x_2$?

Comment: @Gödel sure, that is true.

Comment: @Billy post a new answer, I think that is a nice point as well. Mine was moreso not considering subspaces of potentially infinite spaces, but it is true that no matter which way, in the subspace topology your argument works.

Comment: @Gödel That is a simple modification.  Instead of $x_2$, cover the first $x_i$ such that $x_i \notin U$ (assuming that all points are not already covered).  We know that this will always be possible.

Comment: Your argument is rather vague. For starters, you should define what your terms refer to.

Comment: @Acccumulation I fail to see anywhere where the terms are unclear. I also don’t know where your criticism is either

Comment: The notation {Ux} is vague. You call this "induction", but there is no base case, inductive hypothesis, or proof of the n+1 case. I guess your idea is to take a Ui for each xi, and then the collection of Ui is then a finite subcover, but you just leave that to the reader to figure out.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, one point set is always compact in any topological space, because it will be contained in an open set of any cover and that is the finite one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Suppose the open sets $U_i$ with $i$ in some index set $I$ cover your one-point set $\{x\}$.
Covering this set means that $x\in U_i$ for some $i\in I$.
Therefore your one-point set is contained in a single open set of your open cover.
This is certainly a finite subcover!

Notice that the argument did not use the fact that the sets $U_i$ are open.
This is a symptom of generality:
It is true for any sets $U_i$ and therefore for any topology of the ambient space at all.

Comment: While your second paragraph is true, there are not too many topologies on a one-point set. ;)

Comment: @MaoWao I was referring to the topology of the ambient space, where there might be a bigger selection. :) I'll edit to clarify that...